# Time addition in python

Tags: python, time

i simplify my code:

```
print "hello"

# BeginTime is time in this moment e.g. 9h 45m 23s
# timeplus10s is time 9h 45m 33s

while BeginTime < timeplus10s:
    print "i'm doing something"
print "hello after 10 seconds"
```

as you can see i wanna create construction in while cycle that will last for 10 seconds.

I can't use `time.sleep()` because I need to do something (which you can'
t see because it's simplified).

How can i do that?

Comment: That is not valid Python.

Comment: ...and now code fixed.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds that a task executing during on time frame, try it out:

```
import datetime as d

def task():
    print "I'm doing something!"

#10 seconds from now
END_TIME = d.datetime.now() + d.timedelta(seconds=10)

while d.datetime.now() < END_TIME:
    task()

print "hello after 10 seconds"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import time

print "hello"

# BeginTime is time in this moment e.g. 9h 45m 23s
# timeplus10s is time 9h 45m 33s

BeginTime = time.time()
timeplus10s = BeginTime + 10
while BeginTime < timeplus10s:
    BeginTime = time.time()
    print "i'm doing something"

print "hello after 10 seconds"
```

worked for me. Basically, you only need to save the current time and then check how it changed and if it changed the amount you want, you are done.

Answer (score 0):

```
from time import time

print "hello"

end_time = time() + 10
while time() < end_time:
    print "i'm doing something"

print "hello after 10 seconds"
```